# Shipping details information validation in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am using required attribute to check the pattern on my form which get's the user's shipping info etc. I am running into 2 problems now. The required attribute does''t work in Safari or old IE. Also in the address pattern, if there is a "." lets say instead of North, user types in "N.". It comes up as invalid pattern. Is it better to use javascript to validate it? Also what other attributes can I use within my HTML to validate it because I believe pattern doesn't require user to have javascript enabled.

Here is the HTML part of my code in my form:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,}" size="30"/>
<input type="text" name="last_name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,}" size="30"/>
<input type="text" name="address1" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,}" size="30"/>
<input type="text" name="address2" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,}" size="30"/>
<input type="text" name="city" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,}" size="30"/>
<input type="text" name="zip" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}" size="30"/>
<input type="email" name="email" required size="30" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="telephone" required pattern="[0-9]{9,}" size="30"/>
<input type="submit" id="checkout" name="checkout" class="button" value="Checkout" />
```

Comment: About required="required" - it should be required

Comment: Ah, I will change that but it ends up doing the same thing

Comment: @nicael it doesn't make any difference, it's just the code style that gets changed, and I find this more readable

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript for checking what's inside or simply tell the user you're requiring him to type "North" instead of "N.". Users don't really mind those restrictions. For what regards the required attribute: use javascript aswell

Answer (score 0):

Validating names/email/addreses using javascript's `[a-zA-Z]` (or `\w`) is a Bad Idea ™

You are making some pretty limiting assumptions about a valid users name (all tough, even Unicode can *not* represent everybody's name..).
Have a look (for example) here: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/
For example, what about a chinese/arabic/russion/etc woman's last name who married an american (within your target-region) (think even bi-di text..).

Also, an input type 'email' is (as you have found out) new in html5. You can provide a fall-back (shim/polyfill/creation of your own) to validate the email. However.. validating email was already HARD to do and that has become worse (if not impossible without requiring *frequent* updates to the routine) now with all the (new) internationalized (top level) domain-names (for which the list is still growing). Knowing this, ultimately leads to the notion that even a shim/polyfill (external library) is going to have a hard time to correctly validate *valid* email-addresses.

Finally (since you also want to cater to Canada as you told in the chat), addresses:
what about: Côte Saint Luc, Quebec, Canada (just an example)?

Am I serious?
Yes, *Depending on what you are coding for* (region/audience/level of importance).

If you are fine with it, and *understand* the (very real possible) problems, then everything is fine.. as long as you are not using this for some legit government tax-system etc ... Or an airline booking website... etc.

However... the ***solution is actually simple***:

- be relaxed about what you accept (client-side validation shouldn't be necessary for such fields),
- use Unicode for all localized fields (that includes email, and address and name) (accept that you can not solve the problem that Unicode can not represent everybody's name, but in the future that is fixed, for example China will not accept those characters anymore for newborns since (I think) 2012),
- Just make sure there's no malignant code on the server-side!
  **Edit:** you *must* sanitize *every* input on the server-side anyway (never trust on javascript for that), meaning that you *also* should have the code/routines to handle input that your server-side script deemed invalid (something you could communicate to the user using ajax etc. and optionally provide a fallback (full page-refresh) when javascript is disabled).
  Having all this in place, kind of provides you with the 'bonus-feature' that the cross-browser issues you are running into are no longer your problem, you can/should use the new features as icing on the cake: are required values empty or not, does the email address contain an '@', do the strings contain illegal 'Control Codes'/illegal/reserved characters, etc? These features are relatively easy and reliable to shim (just an example: http://html5please.com/#polyfill) if you should want fallback-mechanisms!
- Do NOT forget these 'rules' (where relevant) when handling/passing/storing this data (you wouldn't be the first to accidentally stuff your Unicode data in a database in a localized transcoded code-page)!

Hope this helps!